# Switch statement cases not executing

Tags: atmega2560

Overview:
I am trying to use a switch statement to run different tests. A main menu is displayed on the serial monitor, and then the user is given the option to enter their menu choice in the serial monitor. The menu choice entered in the serial monitor should subsequently run the appropriate case statement.

Issues:
 1. When I enter a choice the case statement for that choice does not run
 2. When I enter a choice my the serial monitor scrolls through my menu 3 times displaying 49, then 13, then 10.

Questions:

1. Why are my case statements not executing?
2. Why does the serial monitor scroll three times displaying these random numbers?

   ```
   //////////////PREPROCESSOR DIRECTIVES/////////

   #include <Wire.h>

   /////////////GLOBAL VARIABLES////////////////

   int ADDRESS_SLAVE = 0x08;
   int ADDRESS_VERSION = 0x00;
   int ADDRESS_STATUS = 0x01;
   int ADDRESS_ENABLE = 0x02;
   int ADDRESS_CONFIG = 0x03;
   int ADDRESS_RESTART = 0x04;
   int ADDRESS_STARTUP_STATE = 0X05;
   int ADDRESS_COMPENDISREG1 = 0X07;
   int ADDRESS_COMPENDISREG2 = 0X08;
   int ADDRESS_COMPENDISREG3 = 0X09;
   int ADDRESS_COMPENDISREG4 = 0X0A;
   int ADDRESS_FAULT = 0X0B;
   int ADDRESS_FAULTMASK = 0X0C;
   int ADDRESS_TEST_MODE = 0X0D;

   ////////////SETUP CONDITIONS/////////////////

   void setup() 
   {
    Wire.setClock(100000); 
    Wire.beginTransmission(byte(ADDRESS_SLAVE));
    Serial.begin(9600); 
   }

   ////////////MAIN FUNCTION///////////////////

   void loop() 
   {

     int choice = 0;

     int const 
               //Clock 100
               CLOCK_FREQ_P = 101,
               CLOCK_FREQ_DIV4 = 102,
               CLOCK_FREQ_DIV8 = 103,
               CLOCK_FREQ_DIV16 = 104,
               CLOCK_FREQ_DIV32 = 105,
               CLOCK_INT_SUPPLY_IBIAS = 106,
               CLK_OK = 107,

               //Bandgap 200
               BG_2p5V = 200,
               BG_MAX_LOAD = 201,
               BG_VBE = 202,
               BG_VP = 203,
               BG_VGATE = 204,
   mainMenu();


      choice = menuChoice();


      switch(choice)
      {
       case CLOCK_FREQ_P :
       {
         Serial.println(F("CLOCK_FREQ_P Not yet built out"));
         while(Serial.available() > 0) 
           {
              int choice = Serial.read();
           }

         delay(10000);
       }
       break;

       case CLOCK_FREQ_DIV4:
       {
         Serial.println(F("CLOCK_FREQ_DIV4 Not yet built out"));
       }
       break;

       case CLOCK_FREQ_DIV8:
       {
         Serial.println(F("FREQ_DIV8 Not yet built out"));
       }
       break;

       case CLOCK_FREQ_DIV16:
       {
         Serial.println(F("CLOCK_FREQ_DIV16 Not yet built out"));
       }
       break;

       case CLOCK_FREQ_DIV32:
       {
         Serial.println(F("CLOCK_FREQ_DIV32 Not yet built out"));
       }
       break;

       case CLOCK_INT_SUPPLY_IBIAS:
       {
         Serial.println(F("CLOCK_INT_SUPPLY_IBIAS Not yet built out"));
       }
       break;

       case CLK_OK:
       {
         Serial.println(F("CLK_OK Not yet built out"));
       }
       break;

       case BG_2p5V:
       {
         Serial.println(F("BG_2p5V Not yet built out"));
       }
       break;

       case BG_MAX_LOAD:
       {
         Serial.println(F("BG_MAX_LOAD Not yet built out"));
       }
       break;

       case BG_VBE:
       {
         Serial.println(F("BG_VBE Not yet built out"));
       }
       break;

       case BG_VP:
       {
         Serial.println(F("BG_VP Not yet built out"));
       }
       break;

       case BG_VGATE:
       {
         Serial.println(F("BG_VGATE Not yet built out"));
       }
       break;

       delay(500);
   }


   ////////////////FUNCTIONS/////FUNCTIONS/////FUNCTIONS/////FUNCTIONS///////////////////////////

   //*******************************************
   //**      Function: Main Menu Display
   //**      Passes: nothing
   //**      Returns: nothing
   //*******************************************

   void mainMenu()
   {
     //Prints main menu to the serial monitor
     Serial.println();
     Serial.println(F("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t       ******************************"));
     Serial.println(F("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t       ******************************"));
     Serial.println(F("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t       **         MAIN MENU        **"));
     Serial.println(F("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t       ******************************"));
     Serial.println(F("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t       ******************************"));
     Serial.println();
     Serial.println(F("\t\t\t\t\t\t ********************************************************************************************************************"));
     Serial.println(F("\t\t\t\t\t\t **   Please type in the number of the test you want to run in the command line window at the top of the screen.   **"));
     Serial.println(F("\t\t\t\t\t\t ********************************************************************************************************************"));
     Serial.println();
     Serial.println();
     //                                        ******************
     //                                        ***  TOP MENU  ***
     //                                        ******************

     Serial.print(F("\t\t\t CLOCKGEN \t\t\t\t BANDGAP \t\t\t GPIO "));
     Serial.println();
     Serial.print(F("\t\t\t   (1) CLK_FREQ_P \t\t\t   (8) BG_2p5V \t\t\t   (13) GPIO0_PD \t (21) GP1_N_Buff \t (29) GP2_Buff_Max \t  "));
     Serial.println();
     Serial.print(F("\t\t\t   (2) CLK_FREQ_Div_4 \t\t\t   (9) BG_MAX_LOAD \t\t   (14) GPIO0_PU \t (22) GP1_W_Buff \t (30) GP2_Buff_Min "));
     Serial.println();
     Serial.print(F("\t\t\t   (3) CLK_FREQ_Div_8 \t\t\t   (10) BG_VBE \t\t\t   (15) GP0_N_Buff \t (23) GP1_Buff_Max \t (31) GPIO3_PD ") );
     Serial.println();
     Serial.print(F("\t\t\t   (4) CLK_FREQ_Div_16 \t\t\t   (11) BG_VP \t\t\t   (16) GP0_W_Buff \t (24) GP1_Buff_Min \t (32) GPIO3_PU "));
     Serial.println();
     Serial.print(F("\t\t\t   (5) CLK_FREQ_Div_32 \t\t\t   (12) BG_VGATE \t\t   (17) GP0_Buff_Max \t (25) GPIO2_PD \t\t (33) GP3_N_BUFF "));
     Serial.println();
     Serial.print(F("\t\t\t   (6) CLK_INT_Supply_(IBias)\t\t\t\t\t\t   (18) GP0_Buff_Min \t (26) GPIO2_PU \t\t (34) GPIO3_W_BUFF "));
     Serial.println();
     Serial.print(F("\t\t\t   (7) CLK_OK \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t   (19) GPIO1_PD \t (27) GP2_N_Buff \t (35) GP3_BUFF_Max "));
     Serial.println();
     Serial.print(F("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t   (20) GPIO1_PU \t (28) GP2_W_Buff \t (36) GP3_BUFF_Min "));
     Serial.println();
     Serial.println();
     //                                        *********************
     //                                        ***  CENTER MENU  ***
     //                                        *********************

     Serial.print(F("\t\t\t VBUS COMPARITOR \t\t\t\t\t\t\t VAC COMPARITOR \t\t ISNS COMPARITOR \t\t TSNS COMPARITOR"));
     Serial.println();
     Serial.print(F("\t\t\t   (37) CLK_FREQ_P \t(47) BG_2p5V \t(57) GPIO0_PD \t\t\t   (61) GP1_N_Buff \t\t  (68) GP2_Buff_Max \t\t   (74) VB 2.715V Comparitor Test"));
     Serial.println();
     Serial.print(F("\t\t\t   (38) CLK_FREQ_P \t(48) BG_2p5V \t(58) GPIO0_PD \t\t\t   (62) GP1_N_Buff \t\t  (69) GP2_Buff_Max \t\t   (75) VB 2.715V Comparitor Test"));
     Serial.println();
     Serial.print(F("\t\t\t   (39) CLK_FREQ_P \t(49) BG_2p5V \t(59) GPIO0_PD \t\t\t   (63) GP1_N_Buff \t\t  (70) GP2_Buff_Max \t\t   (76) VB 2.715V Comparitor Test"));
     Serial.println();
     Serial.print(F("\t\t\t   (40) CLK_FREQ_P \t(50) BG_2p5V \t(60) GPIO0_PD \t\t\t   (64) GP1_N_Buff \t\t  (71) GP2_Buff_Max \t\t   (77) VB 2.715V Comparitor Test"));
     Serial.println();
     Serial.print(F("\t\t\t   (41) CLK_FREQ_P \t(51) BG_2p5V \t\t\t\t\t   (65) GPIO0_PD \t\t  (72) GP1_N_Buff \t\t\t\t"));
     Serial.println();
     Serial.print(F("\t\t\t   (42) CLK_FREQ_P \t(52) BG_2p5V \t\t\t\t\t   (66) GPIO0_PD \t\t  (73) GP1_N_Buff \t\t\t\t"));
     Serial.println();
     Serial.print(F("\t\t\t   (43) CLK_FREQ_P \t(53) BG_2p5V \t\t\t\t\t   (67) GPIO0_PD \t\t\t\t\t"));
     Serial.println();
     Serial.print(F("\t\t\t   (44) CLK_FREQ_P \t(54) BG_2p5V \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"));
     Serial.println();
     Serial.print(F("\t\t\t   (45) CLK_FREQ_P \t(55) BG_2p5V \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"));
     Serial.println();
     Serial.print(F("\t\t\t   (46) CLK_FREQ_P \t(56) BG_2p5V \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"));
     Serial.println();
     Serial.println();
     Serial.println();
     //                                        *********************
     //                                        ***  BOTTOM MENU  ***
     //                                        *********************

     Serial.print(F("\t\t\t QR COMPARITOR \t\t\t ADC \t\t\t MS Driver \t\t\t AC Driver \t\t\t Active Clamp FET \t\t  V10"));
     Serial.println();
     Serial.print(F("\t\t\t   (78) CLK_FREQ_P \t\t  (84) BG_2p5V \t\t  (87) GPIO0_PD \t\t  (96) GP1_N_Buff \t\t  (100) AC_FET_LEAKAGE \t\t   (1400) V10MIN_V10_OK_FAL"));
     Serial.println();
     Serial.print(F("\t\t\t   (79) CLK_FREQ_P \t\t  (85) BG_2p5V \t\t  (88) GPIO0_PD \t\t  (97) GP1_N_Buff \t\t  (101) AC_FET_LEAKAGE_SWEEP"));
     Serial.println();
     Serial.print(F("\t\t\t   (80) CLK_FREQ_P \t\t  (86) BG_2p5V \t\t  (89) GPIO0_PD \t\t  (98) GP1_N_Buff \t\t  (102) AC_FET_RDS_ON"));
     Serial.println();
     Serial.print(F("\t\t\t   (81) CLK_FREQ_P \t\t\t\t\t  (90) BG_2p5V \t\t\t  (99) GPIO0_PD"));
     Serial.println();
     Serial.print(F("\t\t\t   (82) CLK_FREQ_P \t\t\t\t\t  (91) BG_2p5V"));
     Serial.println();
     Serial.print(F("\t\t\t   (83) CLK_FREQ_P \t\t\t\t\t  (92) BG_2p5V"));
     Serial.println();
     Serial.print(F("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  (93) CLK_FREQ_P"));
     Serial.println();
     Serial.print(F("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  (94) CLK_FREQ_P"));
     Serial.println();
     Serial.print(F("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  (95) CLK_FREQ_P"));
     Serial.println();
     Serial.println();
     Serial.println();  
     Serial.println();
     Serial.println();
     Serial.println();  

   }

   //*******************************************
   //**      Function: menuChoice
   //**      Passes: nothing
   //**      Returns: integer for menu choice
   //*******************************************

   int menuChoice()
   {
     int selection = 0;

     while (Serial.available() == 0);
     {
     selection = Serial.read();
     Serial.print("You entered: ");
     (int)Serial.println(selection, DEC);
     }
     return selection;
   }
   ```

Comment: 49, 13 and 10 are ASCII codes of characters you send from Serial Monitor

Comment: Hi Juraj...I understand these are ASCII codes, but it doesnt make sense if I enter 1, I get a 49 (1),13(carriage return), 10 returned (new line). Do have any idea how I can resolve this?

Comment: Why are you saying that it doesn't make sense? The codes that you receive are exactly what you typed and sent.

Comment: why are you not printing the value of `choice` right after `choice = menuChoice();`? .... that is a simple way of debugging the program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is with the `menuChoice()` function. Try replacing it with this:

```cpp
int menuChoice()
{
  int selection = 0;
  const byte bufferSize = 16;
  char inputBuffer[bufferSize + 1];

  if(Serial.available() > 0){
    // 50 bytes more in compile size using parseInt() vs
    // char buffer and atoi().
    // selection = Serial.parseInt();
    Serial.readBytesUntil('\n', inputBuffer, bufferSize);
    selection = atoi(inputBuffer);
    memset(inputBuffer, 0, sizeof(inputBuffer));
    Serial.print("You entered: ");
    Serial.println(selection, DEC);
  }

  return selection;
}
```

Of course, you could use `parseInt()` instead of the `char` buffer and `atoi()`, but the compile size is 50 bytes more.

Comment: Thanks VE7JRO! The parseInt() function fixed most of this problem. It still seems to pick up the carriage return; I would normally capture the carriage return with cin.get() in C/C++, but I don't know of a similar function available for Arduino. I did try to run the code you provided above, but the menu loops endlessly. Anyway...thanks again for bringing parseInt()to my attention...it helped a bunch!